# Use Sample data directory from a library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, sample-data

I created Sample data directory for my Android app using the process described in [this](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/tool-time-part-2/) article. I would like to share this set of sample data between my projects, so I created a library that only has sample data inside. But as far as I can see `sampledata` folder is not being compiled into the library. Is there a way to share sample data between multiple Android projects?

Comment: Which type of library did you create?

Comment: Android library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already said, you can't do that with a library because `sampledata` simply can't be part of an Android library.

One thing you could though, host your `names` file somewhere and then fetch it with a gradle task, you could just add to an app's `build.gradle`

```
clean.doFirst {
    println "cleanSamples"
    def samplesDir = new File(projectDir.absolutePath, "sampledata")
    if (samplesDir.exists()) {
        samplesDir.deleteDir()
    }
}

task fetchSamples {
    println "fetchSamples"
    def samplesDir = new File(projectDir.absolutePath, "sampledata")
    if (samplesDir.exists()) {
        println "samples dir already exists"
        return
    }    
    samplesDir.mkdir()

    def names = new File(samplesDir, "names")

    new URL('http://path/to/names').withInputStream { i ->
        names.withOutputStream {
            it << i
        }
    }
}
```

You can see 2 functions there, the first one is run before a `clean` task and it will just delete your `sampledata` folder. The second one is a task run on every build, it won't download the file every time but only if the directory is not there.

I understand you might as well copy paste `names` file, but, with this method you need to copy paste the tasks only once and you would be able to change `names` in any project just by uploading a new file and doing a clean build.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, you can't do that with `sampledata` folder.  Basically, the format of the Android Libraries is `AAR`. If you [reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents) the official documentation, it says that:

> The file itself is a zip file containing the following mandatory entries:
>
> /AndroidManifest.xml 
>   /classes.jar
>   /res/
>   /R.txt
>   /public.txt
>
> Additionally, an AAR file may include one or more of the following optional entries:
>
> /assets/
>   /libs/name.jar
>   /jni/abi_name/name.so (where abi_name is one of the Android supported ABIs)
>   /proguard.txt
>   /lint.jar

So, `sampledata` can't be a part of `AAR` library.

**UPDATE**

Instead of your own data samples, you can use [predefined](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#toolssample_resources) sample resources. 
For example `@tools:sample/first_names` will randomly select from some common first names, eg., Sophia, Jacob, Ivan. 

 Example of usage:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="@tools:sample/first_names" />
```

Comment: And do you know is there any other way to have it shared between multiple projects?

Comment: I spent plenty of hours but didn't reach any result. You can use any of your resources as sample data in the `layout`.  The only limitation which I know, it's impossible to use `JSON` as described in your tutorial.

Comment: The main problem for me with `resources` is that in repeatable elements (item in `RecyclerView`) same text will be shown over and over. And I am also not sure will resource referenced by `tools:` be removed by ProGuard.
Anyway, thanks for the help. I will leave this question opened for couple more days, and if there is no better answer you will get the bounty.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović I've updated my answer. It will help you avoid the same data in each row of `RecyclerView`

Comment: I know about those, but I like to have "Jake" in the list of names. :)
It's just weird to me that there is no way to have custom samples available for multiple projects, without copy/paste.